# Display result of a function in html div

Tags: javascript

I'm new to javascript and I'm trying to create a web application that allows the user to input their date of birth and in return, it gives back their Ghanan name according to the day of the week.

I've tried some answers from an article with the same result but it's not working on my end.
`document.getElementById();`

```js
var male = ["Kwasi", "Kwadwo", "Kwabena", "Kwaku", "Yaw", "Kofi", "Kwame"];
var female = ["Akosu", "Adwoa", "Abenaa", "Akua", "Yaa", "Afua", "Ama"];
var dayOfTheWeek = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednsday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
var dayCalculate = parseInt(((CC / 4) - 2 * CC - 1) + ((5 * YY / 4)) + ((26 * (MM + 1) / 10))) % 7;
var gender = document.getElementById('genders').value;
var gender;

if (document.getElementById('male').checked) {
  gender = document.getElementById('male').value;

} else if (gender = document.getElementById('female').checked) {
  gender = document.getElementById('female').value;

  alert(" Since you were born on " + dayOfTheWeek + " Your name is " + female);
}
}
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = dayOfTheWeek;
```

```html
<form id="myform">
  <input type="date" id="birth" />
  <div class="input" id="genders">
    <input type="radio" id="female" name="female" value="female">Female
    <input type="radio" id="male" name="male" value="male">Male
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submitButton" onsubmit=a kanName(); />
</form>
```

I expect an alert which shows the birthdate and then writes the users Akan name in the empty div in HTML.
Here is the error I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: akanName is not defined`

Comment: `"message": "SyntaxError: expected expression, got '}'",`

Comment: `onsubmit=akanName()` (after fixing the typo) tells the browser that when the button gets clicked it should execute a function named `akanName`. But there's no such function, hence the `ReferenceError`

Comment: `gender = document.getElementById('female').checked` is **assignment**, not comparison. For comparison, use `==` or `===` (includes type).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately `CC` is undefined in your code and it isn't exactly clear what you want to achieve. This fixes some basic errors you made:

```js
var male = ["Kwasi", "Kwadwo", "Kwabena", "Kwaku", "Yaw", "Kofi", "Kwame"];
var female = ["Akosu", "Adwoa", "Abenaa", "Akua", "Yaa", "Afua", "Ama"];
var dayOfTheWeek = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednsday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
// var dayCalculate = parseInt(((CC / 4) - 2 * CC - 1) + ((5 * YY / 4)) + ((26 * (MM + 1) / 10))) % 7;
var gender = document.getElementById('genders').value;
var gender;

myform.addEventListener('submit', function akaName(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // prevents the submitting of the form, which would reload the page
  const birthDay = new Date(birth.value).getDay();
  if (document.getElementById('male').checked) {
    gender = document.getElementById('male').value;

  } else if (document.getElementById('female').checked) {
    gender = document.getElementById('female').value;
    alert(" Since you were born on " + dayOfTheWeek[birthDay] + " Your name is " + female[birthDay]);
  }
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = female[birthDay];
});
```

```html
<form id="myform">
  <input type="date" id="birth" />
  <div class="input" id="genders">
    <input type="radio" id="female" name="sex" value="female">Female
    <input type="radio" id="male" name="sex" value="male">Male
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submitButton" />
</form>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: CC is defined, I declared it as a variable:Here is the code

Comment: ```document.getElementById('myform').onsubmit =
function akanName() {
var birth = document.getElementById('birth').value;
alert('Your date of birth is ' + birth);
var CC, YY, MM, DD;
var CC = dob.slice(0,2);
var YY = dob.slice(2,4);
var MM = dob.slice(5,7);
var DD = dob.slice(8,10);
```

Comment: Now `dob` is undefined. You must put all relevant code in your question, not in comments.

Answer (score 0):

There are some undefined variables like

```
CC
YY
MM
```

on your code, pass the appropriate variable 
i have made a working function out of your code

```js
function akanName(){
    var male = ["Kwasi", "Kwadwo", "Kwabena", "Kwaku", "Yaw", "Kofi", "Kwame"];
    var female = ["Akosu", "Adwoa", "Abenaa", "Akua", "Yaa", "Afua", "Ama"];
    var dayOfTheWeek = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednsday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
    let CC=4;
    let YY=2002;
    let MM=3;
    var dayCalculate = parseInt(((CC / 4) - 2 * CC - 1) + ((5 * YY / 4)) + ((26 * (MM + 1) / 10))) % 7;
    var gender = document.getElementById('genders').value;
    var gender;
    
    if (document.getElementById('male').checked) {
      gender = document.getElementById('male').value;
    
    } else if (gender = document.getElementById('female').checked) {
      gender = document.getElementById('female').value;
    
      alert(" Since you were born on " + dayOfTheWeek + " Your name is " + female);
    }
    
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = dayOfTheWeek;
    }
```

```html
    <div id="result">
    
    </div>
    <div id="myform">
      <input type="date" id="birth" />
      <div class="input" id="genders">
        <input type="radio" id="female" name="female" value="female">Female
        <input type="radio" id="male" name="male" value="male">Male
      </div>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submitButton" onclick="akanName();" />
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function akanName() {

  var input = document.getElementById('birth').value;
  var d = new Date(input);
  var CC, MM, YY;
  if (!!d.valueOf()) {
    YY = d.getFullYear();
    MM = d.getMonth();
    CC = d.getDate();
  } else { /* Invalid date */ }
  var male = ["Kwasi", "Kwadwo", "Kwabena", "Kwaku", "Yaw", "Kofi", "Kwame"];
  var female = ["Akosu", "Adwoa", "Abenaa", "Akua", "Yaa", "Afua", "Ama"];
  var dayOfTheWeek = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednsday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
  var dayCalculate = parseInt(((CC / 4) - 2 * CC - 1) + ((5 * YY / 4)) + ((26 * (MM + 1) / 10))) % 7;
  dayCalculate = dayCalculate - 1;
  var gender = document.getElementById('genders').value;
  console.log(dayCalculate);
  if (document.getElementById('male').checked) {
    gender = document.getElementById('male').value;
    alert(" Since you were born on " + dayOfTheWeek[dayCalculate] + " Your name is " + male[dayCalculate]);

  }
  if (document.getElementById('female').checked) {
    gender = document.getElementById('female').value;
    alert(" Since you were born on " + dayOfTheWeek[dayCalculate] + " Your name is " + female[dayCalculate]);
  }
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = dayOfTheWeek[dayCalculate];
}
```

```html
<form id="myform">
  <input type="date" id="birth" />
  <div class="input" id="genders">
    <input type="radio" id="female" name="gender" value="female">Female
    <input type="radio" id="male" name="gender" value="male">Male
  </div>
  <input type="button" value="Submit" id="submitButton" onclick="akanName()" />
  <div>Result:<span id="result"></span></div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it's working well, only that it's not displaying the result on that div.